# SQL Injection via table name?

Tags: sql-injection, sql-server

Is it possible to perform SQL injection on a query where the name of the table is passed in as an argument?  The user doesn't enter the table name themselves, but it can be inferred through element IDs.  I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2012 with Coldfusion 10, if that helps.

Example:

> SELECT * FROM [Database].[dbo].[#tableName#]

Could the #tableName# parameter be used to inject malicious code?

Also, could the parameter names be vulnerable to injection as well?

Second example:

> SELECT * FROM [Database].[dbo].[#tableName#] WHERE [#paramName#] = '#paramValue#'

The second example assumes the use of Coldfusion's cfqueryparam for setting the #paramValue#, so the question is more geared towards the use of [#paramName#].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes**. I'm assuming that you are building your query with string concatenation.

Let's take

```
SELECT * FROM [Database].[dbo].[#tableName#]
```

If you replace #tableName# by `employee]; DELETE FROM [Database].[dbo].[employee` you then obtain 2 queries

```
SELECT * FROM [Database].[dbo].[employee];
DELETE FROM [Database].[dbo].[employee];
```

There is only one way to fix SQL Injection : **use parametrized queries.**